# Can the adjective phrase describe the object of a sentence like this?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

Could you please tell me if the sentences I have written are grammatically correct? Can I use adjectives to describe the object of the sentence like this:

1. He hung the flowers on the wall, dried and hanging upside down.
2. Kelly's aunt gave her the cake, frosted and fresh out of the oven.

Are the adjectives correctly referring back to the "flowers" and the "cake"?

Comment: If you omit the word **hanging** from sentence 1, the sentence is fine. There is no problem with sentence 2.

Comment: @RonaldSole  agreed, but mostly because it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

> "He hung the flowers on the wall, dried and hanging upside down."

The main problem here is repetition of the verb "to hang". I suggest:

*He hung the dried flowers upside-down on the wall.*

or

*He hung the flowers, dried and upside down, on the wall.*

Answer (score 0):

> "He hung the flowers on the wall, dried and hanging upside down."

I would say that this sentence is syntactically correct but that there is something about the standard usage of present active participles paired with perfect passive participles which makes the use of "hanging" sound bizarre.

> "Kelly's aunt gave her the cake, frosted and fresh out of the oven."

This sentence is correct.

The adjectives you specify do have the proper antecedents.